# keithley 2600B control using pyvisa

Tags: python, pyvisa

I tried to use pyvisa to communicate with keithley 2600B DC power supply. The instrument was configured for web socket control.
Using NI MAX, I can find the instrument in Network devices, and the address is like `TCPIP0::XXX.XXX.X.X::2268::SOCKET`.

First, if I use NI VISA, the `visa.ResourceManager()` can't find the instrument.

Then I installed `pyvisa-py`, but still `visa.ResourceManager('@py')` can't find the instrument.

Then I use `rm.open_resource('TCPIP0::XXX.XXX.X.X::2268::SOCKET')`, and send command `*IDN?` it still gives error:

`VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.`

anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it plugged in? That's when I usually get my timeouts.

Comment: I am sure it is plugged in. In fact, I have a labview program works, and try to write python to control it too. Strange thing is that after run the labview program with no problem, then I run python code, and the error showed up. Then I run labview program again, and it didn't work too. Then I have to turn off the DC power supply, and turn on again, the labview program works again. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: So you don't close the port in labvuew?